# MYSQL: Select items that do not contain a certain date

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table

```
CustID   |   OrderDate
1        |   2017-05-30 05:15:18
2        |   2017-04-18 05:15:18
2        |   2017-04-15 05:15:18
3        |   2017-02-17 05:15:18
4        |   2017-05-29 05:15:18
4        |   2017-03-24 05:15:18
```

Any I only want to return back the CustIDs that do not contain an order date newer than 30 days (Today being 2017-05-30). So the above example would only return 2 and 3.

I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustID
FROM TABLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustID FROM TABLE WHERE OrderDate > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL-30DAY));
```

But I only get syntax errors.

Thanks again, I am quite new with SQL.

Comment: Can you please give example for your requirement with some specific date and your required output?

Comment: Please accept the answer below if it helped you to achieve what you were looking for. This way, it won't be lost in thread and would help others who have similar issues :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select distinct CustIDs from YourTableName where OrderDate < now() - interval 30 day;
```

PS: In your query, you're using `FROM TABLE` - it isn't right, you must use `FROM {YourTableName}`, where `{YourTableName}` is real name of your table in database, like (customers, clients, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

because you're missing a vital component in where clause: `and t1.id = t2.id`

`select distinct CustID from table t1 where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where [whatever_your_conditions_are] and t1.id = t2.id);`

A table similar to yours... It just has date instead of timestamp (and a relaxed date condition in where clause, just for the sake of simplicity):

[image]

selecting the users whose date > current_date (which is order_date in your case):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your question.

your query will be:

`SELECT DISTINCT CustID FROM TABLE WHERE OrderDate < GETDATE()-30`

Let me know if you  require changes like `<` or `>` `OrderDate` in `Where` Clause.